# What is the best way to setup a jQuery timeout interval?

Tags: jquery

According to [[ http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timeout_interval_idle ]], I should be able to say:

```
$.interval(function() { alert('I happen every 8 seconds'); }, 8000);
```

and have the given function run every eight seconds.

However the error console says `$.interval is not a function`.  I have tried this under jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.4.3, both give the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Simply try `setInterval`:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  alert('I happen every 8 seconds');
}, 8000);
```

use `clearInterval` to stop. You might have a look at [mozilla's developer center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

That's a plugin that has to be included *after* jQuery core.

However it's not needed, a simpler [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) will do (no jQuery required), like this:

```
setInterval(function() { alert('I happen every 8 seconds'); }, 8000);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nRWcc/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard jQuery operator but instead a function provided by the referenced plugin.  It won't be available unless you explicitly import the plugin into your code base.

Alternatively you could just use the `setInterval` function directly.

```
setInterval(function() { alert('I happen every 8 seconds'); }, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the plug in code in your page? This isn't part of jQuery itself, so you need to make sure you have [the plugin file](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.timeout.interval.idle.js_0.txt) either linked to as a separate script or inline in your page.

I'm not sure what functionality this plugin offers beyond what the standard window.setInterval function does.

Comment: This plugin seems to be founded on ignorance. From its docs: *"These functions [setTimeout and setInterval] are very useful, but unfortunately they only accept code as a string."* It's apparently too easy to create jQuery plugins.

Answer (score -3):

Use `setTimeout()` instead of `$.interval()`

Comment: a timeout is not the same as an interval, a timeout executes *once*.